# Lua script to trigger Python script?

Tags: python, lua, listener, wireshark

I'm writing a Lua script for a Wireshark Listener. I would like the Lua script to open a Python script at the end of the file.

I've looked at other solutions but Lunatic-Python or other libraries are not what I'm looking for. I don't want to run Python functions in Lua, I just want Lua to "double click" on a Python script to open it.

I've tried os.execute(), but that opens a cmd Window for a couple seconds. When I double click on the Python script it runs as I want it to. I would like Lua to trigger similar to that.

Comment: Looks like `os.execute` does exactly what you want: the Python script's short and runs very quickly, so the cmd window opens, shows the execution process and shuts down, as it should do.

Comment: Best way to test if it's calling a python script or not, create a dummy script with like `x = input('hello')` and if the cmd window opens and you see `'hello'` and it hangs, then it's working as intended.

Comment: @ForceBru You're absolutely correct, I was hoping the user could input something but my script just runs. Thanks!

Comment: And thank you @MooingRawr, the test script worked as intended! I just need to add some lines so my script "hangs".